# Combine all posts into one places

Tags: custom-post-types

I have post type: All items, i need in this All items display posts from post type: Archive and Recent, how i can in post type All items - get posts form 2 post types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to setup a new query to get posts from another post_type.
The post_type parameter will accept an array, so you can just do:

```
$other_posts = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => [ 'archive', 'recent' ], // or what ever your post_types are.
]);

// Then do your loop...
```

Check this documentation for more information.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-type-parameters

Comment: i need just output in one post type all posts with another post types